# In OSGi, ServiceLoader.load fails to find an implementation

Tags: java, apache, osgi, serviceloader

We have been trying to get SPI Fly to work with **openstack4j-core** and one of the openstack4j connectors (**openstack4j-httpclient**). It is `org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExecutorService` that require the SPIFly weaving.

One quirk: both bundles are loaded from a zip file and started after the rest of the system is up and running. The same zip file provides  the `org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle`.

The two bundles do use the OSGI-Spec compliant model from [the standard set of instructions for SPI Fly](http://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html#specconf).
Per these instructions, all we really need is the appropriate `Require-Capability` and `Provide-Capability` headers in the MANIFEST.MF of both bundles, plust the service declaration under **META-INF/** (shown below).

The core bundle has:

```
Require-Capability: 
osgi.serviceloader;filter:="(osgi.serviceloader=org.openstack4j.api.APIProvider)";cardinality:=multiple,
osgi.serviceloader;filter:="(osgi.serviceloader=org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExecutorService)";cardinality:=multiple,
osgi.serviceloader;filter:="(osgi.serviceloader=org.openstack4j.openstack.logging.LoggerFactorySupplier)";cardinality:=multiple;resolution:=optional,
osgi.extender;filter:="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.processor)",
osgi.extender;filter:="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.registrar)",
osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"
```

And the httpclient one has:

```
Require-Capability: osgi.extender;filter:="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.registrar)",osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

Provide-Capability: osgi.serviceloader;osgi.serviceloader="org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExecutorService"
```

(Re-formatted for readability, of course)

Additionally, the  **openstack4j-httpclient** has the file named `org.openstack4j.core.transport.HttpExecutorService` under **META-INF/services**, with the single line:

```
org.openstack4j.connectors.httpclient.HttpExecutorServiceImpl
```

We also add the `org.apache.aries.spifly.dynamic.bundle` bundle, which provides the `serviceloader.processor` and `serviceloader.registrar` capabilities.

Then at runtime, the ServiceLoader call just does not find the `HttpExecutorService`.

PS: Messing with the order in which the bundles are started has not been fruitful and calling `resolveBundles` on `FrameworkWiring` before all the bundles are started has not worked.

Comment: Are there any errors or relevant log messages in the OSGi LogService?